# Insert query is called on add related entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following two models:

`Vergadering`

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Naam { get; set; }
public DateTime DatumTijd { get; set; }
public ICollection<Bestuurslid> Aanwezigen { get; set; }
```

`Bestuurslid`

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Naam { get; set; }
public string Functie { get; set; }
public ICollection<Vergadering> Vergaderingen { get; set; }
```

To add a new `vergadering` I have the following code within my repository:

```
public async Task AddVergaderingAsync()
{
    using (var _db = _factory.CreateDbContext())
    {

        var vergadering = new Vergadering();
        vergadering.Naam = "Lorem ipsum";
        vergadering.DatumTijd = Date.Now;
        vergadering.Aanwezigen = await GetBestuursledenAsync();

        _db.Vergaderingen.Add(vergadering);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

But instead of adding a new record to `VergaderingBestuurslid` table, it tries to create a new `bestuurslid` within the `Bestuursleden` table.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You have to select entity `Vergadering` from the same context. Otherwise EF treats it as the new entity. Probably attaching to context's `ChangeTracker` also may help.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv can you post an example?

Comment: What is `VergaderingBestuurslid` table?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv `Vergadering` is a `meeting`. `Bestuurslid` is a `board member`. Every `Vergadering (meeting)` has multiple `Bestuurslid (board member)`. And every `Bestuurslid (board member)`  can attend multiple `Vergadering`. In the table `VergaderingBestuurslid` this is defined

Comment: When you create new `DbContext`, it's `ChangeTracker` is empty and it has no knowledge about any related entities which comes with `vergadering` instance. So if you just add this entity to `ChangeTracker` all related entities are treated as NEW. And EF Core will insert them. It is difficult to suggest what to do here when there is no knowledge from where `vergadering` is returned.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv can you show an (unrelated) example? I never worked with `ChangeTracker` before. How to add this entity to `ChangeTracker`? Do I add the `Vergadering` to this `ChangeTracker` because this one has to be inserted. Or do I add all known `Bestuurslid` to the `ChangeTracker` because these are the related entities?

Comment: Check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/explicit-tracking#generated-key-values-1)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I added some code to my question within the `repository`. An example of a new `Vergadering`. Is this enough information for you to give an example with the `ChangeTracker`? I couldn't get it to work with the microsoft article.

Comment: Or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/april/data-points-why-does-entity-framework-reinsert-existing-objects-into-my-database) for a still valid explanation of the cause. The key concepts of tracking and entity state haven't changed since the first EF versions.

Comment: GetBestuursledenAsync should use the same DbContext, or you have attach this entity to current context.